# Percentages and trees

Tags: math, tree

I have an unordered tree. 
Each node represents a task that can be done (1), not done (0) or have children tasks.

For example:

```
1
-1.1
-1.2
--1.2.1
--1.2.2
-1.3
2
3
-3.1
4
-4.1
--4.1.1
5
```

Suppose that the leaves 1.2.1, 3.1 and 5 are *done*

```
1
-1.1
-1.2
--1.2.1*
--1.2.2
-1.3
2
3
-3.1*
4
-4.1
--4.1.1
5*
```

I want to calculate the percentage of completeness of each node. The leaves are easily calculated with 0% or 100%, but how to compute all the others?

At the moment, I walk the tree from the leaves on and each node is calculated based on the percentage of completeness of the children. For example:

```
1      50%
-1.1*  100%
-1.2   0%
2      0%
3      33%
-3.1*  100%
-3.2   0%
-3.3   0%
```

Now, more children are added to 1.2 (that is no more a leaf but becomes a node). If the children are "not done", 1.2 is always 0% and so 1 is 50%, but I would like 1 to be *less* then 50%, as, descending into his children and grand-children the number of tasks to be completed in order for it to the done 100% is greater!

```
1       50%
-1.1*   100%
-1.2    0%
--1.2.1 0%
--1.2.2 0%
2       0%
3       33%
-3.1*   100%
-3.2    0%
-3.3    0%
```

What is the best way to calculate this? Thanks

Comment: Disagreeing with most of the answers given yet, I think that until you attach a weightage based system, the percentage of task completion in your existing system is accurate. The no. of subtasks should not matter in the percentage completion of the main (root level) task.

Comment: Well, suppose that I'm building a car from scratch. I have the node "physically build it" with 10.000 subtasks and on the same level the leaf "choose a name". I wouldn't say that, once decided to call it "Oldsmobile2000" I'm halfway done!

Comment: @Cerebrus: you are trying to apply your logic to his problem.  If he wants to compute the % done a certain way, then by definition that is the right way to do it.  I do think that he should add an explicit weight to each node, but he is implicitly doing that by saying that each leaf node has equal weight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define the %done as total (sub)nodes done divided by total (sub) nodes. Counting only the leaves.

In this case:

```
       1  (1/2 = 50%)
      / \
   1.1*  1.2
```

Adding the extra nodes:

```
       1  (1/3 = 33%)
      / \
   1.1*  1.2 (0/2 = 0%)
         / \
    1.2.1   1.2.2
```

If that is not enough, you can add a weight to each task and calculate the completed weight divided by the total weight.

Comment: Nice answer. The graph alone is worth the +1.

Answer (score 1):

For any node,
% done = # of descendant *leaves* done / total # of descendant *leaves*

Where:

number of descendant leaves = sum(childrens' # of descendant leaves)

Answer (score 0):

you could try with a [post order visit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_search) (pseudocode):

```
postorder(node) {

    foreach(child : children) {
        postorder(child)
        node.visited++

        if (child.completed == 1) {
           node.completed++        
        }
    }

    print("%d%%", (node.completed / node.visited) * 100)
}
```

Comment: The solution should only use the leaf nodes. This doesn't respect that constraint.

Comment: why it should use only leaf nodes? that is *WRONG* since "I want to calculate the percentage of completeness of ***each*** node"

Comment: He wants to compute the completeness of each node, yes, but only the leaf nodes count towards the weight. Using your logic, node 1 would compute to 25% done instead of the correct 33%.  As a side note, saying it really loud doesn't make you right, just loud.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the weight you want to give to each level. If I were you I would choose the first method that you mentioned (i.e. put the same weight on items on the same level) so 1 with 50% would look right to me and the difference of having more nodes would be seen by a slower increase of 'done' percentage for 1.2 node.

To get a node to affect more distant ancestors you could calculate the ancestor percentage as an average of *all* the leafs in its subtree (that would give 33% completion for task 1), but this doesn't seem quite right to me. It all depends on how you really want to represent the data - I don't think there's a 'right' way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the percentage of each node is the average value of it's children (not sub-children) percentages.

For example

```
 1_per = (1.1_per + 1.2_per) / 2
 3_per = (3.1_per + 3.2_per + 3.3_per) / 3
```