# Adaptive parent relative to children's attributes in a recursive array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, tree

I'm trying to make a simple tree structure where every task has a certain percentage of completion and its parent has to inherit average completion of its direct children, as seen conceptually on the picture below. (0s are percentages of completion, for example subtask2 could be 100% and subtask2 0%, which would give task1 50% completion and therefore stackoverflow would have 25%, given task2 is at 0)

[image: image 1]

The issue I'm having is that I need to start, apparently, from the deepest children, but I can't seem to figure out how to implement such reversal traversal from leafs to root.

I have tried with normal recursive as well as double for loop and both only achieve first level calculations (in the picture example task1 is calculated, but stackoverflow will remain 0).

Note: **Only leafs** can actually have completion percentage, since every other element, which is not a leaf, inherits percentage from its children. (how paradoxical)

If any of you have any ideas on how to implement such an algorithm, be it conceptually or actual code, I would very much appreciate any input.

Below is structure of this array (only kept relevant information):

```
[0] => Array
(
    [title] => stackoverflow
    [completion] => 0
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => task2
                    [completion] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array 
                (
                    [title] => task1
                    [completion] => 0
                    [children] => Array 
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [title] => subtask2
                                    [completion] => 100
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [title] => subtask1
                                    [completion] => 0
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I seem to be having a similar issue than the issue in this thread: [Percentages and trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063432/percentages-and-trees?rq=1) however, I need my task to have actual percentages, not only completed/non-completed. All math is completely linear, meaning that parent's percentage = (addition of all percentages of children) / (number of children)

Also var_export:

```
array (
      0 => 
      array (
            'uuid' => '157ed2b2-0d0c-4f0c-b1d2-7126255f4023',
            'title' => 'stackoverflow',
            'completed' => '0',
            'parent' => NULL,
            'children' => 
                array (
                  0 => 
                  array (
                    'uuid' => '72ce49a6-76e5-495e-a3f8-0f13d955a3b5',
                    'title' => 'task2',
                    'completed' => '0',
                    'parent' => '157ed2b2-0d0c-4f0c-b1d2-7126255f4023',
                  ),
              1 => 
              array (
                    'uuid' => '4975d08d-55f0-4cd8-9de5-2d056111ec2d',
                    'title' => 'task1',
                    'completed' => '0',
                    'parent' => '157ed2b2-0d0c-4f0c-b1d2-7126255f4023',
                    'children' => 
                        array (
                          0 => 
                          array (
                            'uuid' => 'ac5e9d37-8f14-4169-bcf2-e7b333c5faea',
                            'title' => 'subtask2',
                            'completed' => '0',
                            'parent' => '4975d08d-55f0-4cd8-9de5-2d056111ec2d',
                          ),
                      1 => 
                      array (
                        'uuid' => 'f74b801f-c9f1-40df-b491-b0a274ffd301',
                        'title' => 'subtask1',
                        'completed' => '0',
                        'parent' => '4975d08d-55f0-4cd8-9de5-2d056111ec2d',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
)
```

Comment: What does your input array look like?

Comment: Just added it :)

Comment: Please, use `var_export` for your array, not `var_dump`, so we can copy/paste it.

Comment: Added var_export as well, albeit I've had some problems with formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recursive function that passes the parent by reference until it finds a leaf and updates totals working backward.

```
function completionTree(&$elem, &$parent=NULL) {
    // Handle arrays that are used only as a container... if we have children but no uuid, simply descend.
    if (is_array($elem) && !isset($elem['uuid'])) {
        foreach($elem AS &$child) {
            completionTree($child, $elem);
        }
    }

    // This array has children. Iterate recursively for each child.
    if (!empty($elem['children'])) {
        foreach ($elem['children'] AS &$child) {
            completionTree($child, $elem);
        }
    }

    // After recursion to handle children, pass completion percentages up to parent object
    // If this is the top level, nothing needs to be done (but suppress that error)
    if (@$parent['completed'] !== NULL) {
        // Completion must be multiplied by the fraction of children it represents so we always add up to 100. Since values are coming in as strings, cast as float to be safe.
        $parent['completed'] = floatval($parent['completed']) + (floatval($elem['completed']) * (1/count($parent['children'])));
    }
}

// Data set defined statically for demonstration purposes
$tree = array(array (
            'uuid' => '157ed2b2-0d0c-4f0c-b1d2-7126255f4023',
            'title' => 'stackoverflow',
            'completed' => '0',
            'parent' => NULL,
            'children' => 
                array (
                  0 => 
                  array (
                    'uuid' => '72ce49a6-76e5-495e-a3f8-0f13d955a3b5',
                    'title' => 'task2',
                    'completed' => '0',
                    'parent' => '157ed2b2-0d0c-4f0c-b1d2-7126255f4023',
                  ),
              1 => 
              array (
                    'uuid' => '4975d08d-55f0-4cd8-9de5-2d056111ec2d',
                    'title' => 'task1',
                    'completed' => '0',
                    'parent' => '157ed2b2-0d0c-4f0c-b1d2-7126255f4023',
                    'children' => 
                        array (
                          0 => 
                          array (
                            'uuid' => 'ac5e9d37-8f14-4169-bcf2-e7b333c5faea',
                            'title' => 'subtask2',
                            'completed' => '0',
                            'parent' => '4975d08d-55f0-4cd8-9de5-2d056111ec2d',
                          ),
                      1 => 
                      array (
                        'uuid' => 'f74b801f-c9f1-40df-b491-b0a274ffd301',
                        'title' => 'subtask1',
                        'completed' => '100',
                        'parent' => '4975d08d-55f0-4cd8-9de5-2d056111ec2d',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
);

// Launch recursive calculations
completionTree($tree);

// Dump resulting tree
var_dump($tree);
```

Comment: The only thing I had to change was the formula, since only leafs can actually have values, so: $parent['completed'] = floatval($parent['completed']) + (floatval($elem['completed'])) * (1/count($parent['children']));. But this is exactly what I wanted, thanks man, the main issue I was actually having was passing by reference, because it never did update the original element for some reason in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Though this is answered, I'd like to leave a solution that seems *a bit* more intuitive (IMHO). Instead of passing down the parent, just handle the children first:

```
/**
 * @param array $nodes
 *
 * @return array
 */
function calcCompletion(array $nodes): array {
    // for each node in nodes
    return array_map(function (array $node): array {
        // if it has children
        if (array_key_exists('children', $node) && is_array($node['children'])) {
            // handle the children first
            $node['children'] = calcCompletion($node['children']);

            // update this node by *averaging* the children values
            $node['completed'] = array_reduce($node['children'], function (float $acc, array $node): float {
                return $acc + floatval($node['completed']);
            }, 0.0) / count($node['children']);
        }

        return $node;
    }, $nodes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this might be a little overhead, but you can use [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php). First, you must extend it to handle your tree structure:

```
class MyRecursiveTreeIterator extends RecursiveArrayIterator
{
    public function hasChildren()
    {
        return isset($this->current()['children']) 
            && is_array($this->current()['children']);    
    }

    public function getChildren()
    {
        return new static($this->current()['children']);
    }
}
```

Then using [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) you can create an iterator which will process your tree starting from leaves:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new MyRecursiveTreeIterator($tasks),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
);
```

Then with this one, you can add your calculation logic:

```
$results = [];
$temp = [];
$depth = null;

foreach ($iterator as $node) {
    if ($iterator->getDepth() === 0) {
        // If there were no children use 'completion'
        // else use children average
        if (
            is_null($depth)
            || !isset($temp[$depth])
            || !count($temp[$depth])
        ) {
            $percentage = $node['completed']; 
        } else {
            $percentage = array_sum($temp[$depth]) / count($temp[$depth]);
        }

        $results[$node['title']] = $percentage;
        continue;
    }

    // Set empty array for current tree depth if needed.
    if (!isset($temp[$iterator->getDepth()])) {
        $temp[$iterator->getDepth()] = [];
    }

    // If we went up a tree, collect the average of children
    // else push 'completion' for children of current depth.
    if ($iterator->getDepth() < $depth) {
        $percentage = array_sum($temp[$depth]) / count($temp[$depth]);
        $temp[$depth] = [];
        $temp[$iterator->getDepth()][] = $percentage;
    } else {
        $temp[$iterator->getDepth()][] = $node['completed'];
    }

    $depth = $iterator->getDepth();
}
```

Here is [a demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9452a98531dc548adea0c89648bb8cad411cd7d0).

Comment: Please rewrite your method to use the `$tasks` array that you commented out -- this is the OP's actual input.

Comment: @mickmackusa, as far as I can see they have the same structure.

Comment: I didn't look into why, but when I swap in the full/real array, it doesn't work.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4f58ce57a60e699a1e557ce17a4dce009e1abba1  If you don't want to change your answer, don't.  I'm not your boss and I'm pretty sure you don't like me anyway.

Comment: @mickmackusa, it shows 0 in the result, because all `completed` fields in the second array from the question have 0 value.

Comment: @mickmackusa, as OP stated "Below is structure of this array (only kept relevant information)", that's why I left two versions of an array in the demo.